# Adding to last listbox item

Tags: listbox, items, listboxitems

Let's say I have a listbox and two buttons in a windows form application. When I click button1, "button1" is added to the listbox. When I click button2 "button2" is added as a new entry.

What I'm trying to do is have button2 added next to the previous entry instead of as a new entry. Something like "button1 + button2". Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to update an existing item on the form, not add a new one.  Check this out:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("A");
        listBox1.Items[0] = listBox1.Items[0] + "B";
    }
}
```

Comment: Aha! Exactly what I was looking for thanks! I wasn't able to find this anywhere. I've only been doing C# recently for one of my courses but I'm enjoying it quite a bit, thanks for the help